# Cakephp only loads one .css-file - 403-Error for all others

Tags: php, css, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have a problem which I find fairly strange, maybe someone can help me.

I use cakephp. My web root folder for apache is /home/jw/www. My project is under /home/jw/www/hc2, so the overall folder structure (only the parts important for this question) is:

```
www
 /hc2
  /app
   /webroot
    index.php
    /css
     /cake.generic.css
     /any.css
     /other.css
     /stylesheets.css
    /js
     /any.js
     /javascript.js
     /files.js
```

Well, cakephp works fine so far - routing (with mod_rewrite enabled), database connection etc. works.
The one but huge problem is: No .css- or .js-files are loaded, except the cake.generic.css!
The part of the .cpt-template, where I load css and js files looks something like:

```
echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
echo $this->Html->css('layout');

echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-2.0.3.min');
```

In the html- of the loaded page this becomes e.g.:

```
<link href="/hc2/css/cake.generic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/hc2/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But when I examine those two with firebug, I see that the first of those is loaded correctly - I can see the css-definitions of the file - while the other one receives an error 403!

Is it maybe a mod_rewrite-problem? But since I can access all controllers just the way it should be, I can't quite imagine that... Does anyone maybe have an idea? Would be very happy, thanks...

Comment: `403` is `Forbidden`. Could be any of a number of issues, but as you seem to be using Apache the first step in resolving this is to look at the logs. `$ tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` or something similar.

Comment: error.log shows these for every request I made:
`[Sat Aug 31 15:14:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /home/jw/www/hc2/app/webroot/css/bootstrap.min.css, referer: http://localhost/hc2/Projects/
[Sat Aug 31 15:14:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /home/jw/www/hc2/app/webroot/css/layout.css, referer: http://localhost/hc2/Projects/`
etc. for all .css- and .js-links except cake.generic.css

Answer (score 0):

Sry, I solved it myself - thanks to the help of @mvanderw.

It had nothing to do with cakephp/apache/mod_rewrite whatsoever. The problems were the File permissions. For some reason, I had copied all files except the cake.generic.css (which I downloaded) from my windows file system (on the same device) an for some reason, they were coming with the permissions 600.

chmodded to 644 now and everything works. So maybe this helps someone sometime in the future with a similar problem... :)